# How to catch un-handled exception in Meteor + NodeJs application

Tags: node.js, meteor

we are using Meteor + NodeJS application. Meteor application use for communication for client and Nodejs application for connect to DB. We gave the nodeJS application reference in meteor application.

When any un-handled error occurs in nodejs application we are not able to catch it.

We deploy the meteor and nodejs application as a package.

From Meteor we called nodejs methods using Meteor.wrapAsync(node.method1). 
we are able to catch the exception in meteor till callback from node method. After callback if any exception occurs in nodejs method we are not able to handle it.

Thanks for your replay

Answer (score 1):

Since there isn't any code presented here, I'm going to assume that you have the following scenario:

- You have a Meteor application that calls services that are hosted in a different node server.
- The node services are sharing the same database as the Meteor app.
- Clients only interact with the Meteor app.

Meteor is using its own embedded node server, so service calls to the other node app is actually a communication between two different node servers, which means that they have their own call stack, hence they can't handle each other's exceptions.

The only way to communicate errors between the two is if you handle the exceptions in the node application and send error codes to the Meteor app. They can be either HTTP codes, if you're using ajax, for example, or your own kind of error codes.

Comment: 1. Node application hosted on same server and gave  node application reference in meteor application.  
2. Yes , The node services are sharing the same database as the Meteor app.
3. Yes , Clients only interact with the Meteor app.